# Copying directory multiple times with 1 command

Tags: linux

How can I copy a directory with the name "1" and create directories from 2-150 with the same contents without having to do this individually?

Comment: What shell? `Bash`?

Comment: I'm using linux

Comment: Great, but what shell? What `Linux`? If you don't know it's probably `Bash`. Try this: `mkdir {2..150} && for i in {2..150}; do cp -r 1/* "$i"; done`.